# DropdownMenuItem not found when declared outside of an ExposedDropdownMenu

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material3

I want to create an generic searchbox with autocomplete, where the suggestion list is the result of an external API call.

There is an optional suggestion header and suggestion row's are changed once selected.

To achieve this I wanted to delegate `DropdownMenuItem` instantiation to the caller.

So here is a declaration draft:

```
fun AutoCompleteTextField(
    optionList: ImmutableSet<String>,
    onFilter: (String) -> Unit,
    listHeader: @Composable (() -> DropdownMenuItem)? = null,
    listFooter:  @Composable (() -> DropdownMenuItem)? = null,
    listItem: @Composable ColumnScope.(Int, String) -> DropdownMenuItem
) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = isExpanded,
        onExpandedChange = { isExpanded = !isExpanded }
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = value,
            modifier = Modifier
                .menuAnchor(),
            onValueChange = {
                value = it
                onFilter.invoke(it.text)
            }
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = isExpanded,
            onDismissRequest = { isExpanded = false },
        ) {
            listHeader?.invoke()
            optionList.forEachIndexed { idx, item ->
                listItem.invoke(this, idx, item)
            }
            listFooter?.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

... and how it could be used:

```
AutoCompleteTextField(
    optionList = uiState.searchResults,
    onFilter = viewModel::onFilter,
    listHeader = {
        DropdownMenuItem(
            text = { Text(text = "Add new") },
            onClick = viewModel::onAddClick()
        )
    }
){ idx, option ->
    DropdownMenuItem(
        text = { Text(text = option) },
        trailingIcon = if (option == selected) {
            {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_checkmark),
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }
        } else {
            null
        },
        modifier = Modifier.background(
            if (option == selected) {
                Color.Green
            } else {
                Color.Transparent
            }
        ),
        onClick = viewModel::onSelected(idx, option)
    )
}
```

Unfortunately Android Studio can't find `DropdownMenuItem` in Composable declaration, but it does when it's instantiated as a child of `ExposedDropdownMenu`

[image: Unable to resolve reference to DropdownMenuItem]

I imported `import androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenuItem` and this Composable is not internal.

I don't understand why I can't use it out of DropdownMenu context?
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

`DropdownMenuItem` is not a **type**, it is a **name of a function**, which means you cannot use it the way you are trying to - as a return type. Also, composable functions that emit UI should return `Unit` by convention. You should change the types of arguments of `AutoCompleteTextField` like this:

```kotlin
// listHeader: @Composable (() -> DropdownMenuItem)? = null,
listHeader: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
```

you will be able to use `DropdownMenuItem` inside:

```kotlin
listHeader = {
    DropdownMenuItem(
        text = { Text(text = "Add new") },
        onClick = viewModel::onAddClick()
    )
}
```

This means that you cannot force users of `AutoCompleteTextField` to only use `DropdownMenuItem` as a `listHeader` - they can put any composable inside. This is intentional and by design.